# Using Item functions on metadata values

Tags: msbuild

**Background:** I manage a fairly large solution. Every so often, people add a DLL reference to a project in the solution where they should've added a project reference. I want to issue a warning in such case. I want to do it by finding all reference with 'bin\debug' in their HintPath*. I know that references are Items in ItemGroup, with metadata "HintPath".

I expected something like this to work:

```
<Warning Text="Reference %(Reference.Identity) should be a project reference. HintPath: %(Reference.HintPath)"
         Condition="%(Reference.HintPath).IndexOf('bin\debug') != -1"/>
```

However, Seems like I can't use string function IndexOf like that. I tried many permutations of the above, without success.

- Edit: I know this check is not full-proof, but I just want to reduce honest mistakes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using MSBuild 4.0 [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) it is possible to do string comparisons:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">

  <Message Text="Checking reference... '%(Reference.HintPath)'" Importance="high" />

  <Warning Text="Reference %(Reference.Identity) should be a project reference. HintPath: %(Reference.HintPath)"
            Condition="$([System.String]::new('%(Reference.HintPath)').Contains('\bin\$(Configuration)'))" />

</Target>
```

Comment: +1: I was so into the getting a property from item metadata, that I didn't see this obvious thing. Actually, given your specific need, this looks much better.

Comment: Works for me. I wish I could do case-insensitive lookup - IndexOf('\bin\$(Configuration)',StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) - but MSBuild doesn't seem to be able to invoke functions with overloads.

Comment: +1 When I was trying to solve the issue by miself, I thought about this idea, but did not realize, how to instantiate string object (actually, I'm not too fluent in C#). Thanks for the solution.

Comment: The `::new` trick works in the newest MSBuild, where `::Copy` (suggested in another question) doesn't. Also note: syntax like `Lines="@(ProductConfig->'#define PRODUCT_%(Identity) &quot;$([System.String]::new('%(Text)').Replace(!\!,!\\!))&quot;')"` (`!` stand for backticks, markdown fail) works despite the single quotes around `%(Text)` being nested inside the single quotes of `->`. MSBuild syntax ftw!

Answer (score 2):

First not that your syntax is not correct for invoking functions, it would need to be:

```
   %(Reference.HintPath.IndexOf(...))       # Note: not supported by MSBuild
```

However, property functions in MSBuild are [not allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx) on item metadata, so that is not going to help you either.

What you could work around this, by invoking a separate target which is basically called for every item.

```
  <Target Name="CheckProjectReferences">
    <MSBuild 
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Properties="Identity=%(Reference.Identity);HintPath=%(Reference.HintPath)"
      Targets="_Warn"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="_Warn">
    <Warning Text="Reference $(Identity) should be a project reference. HintPath: $(HintPath)"
             Condition="$(HintPath.IndexOf('bin\debug')) != -1"/>
  </Target>
```

Frankly, I'm not sure if that is enough to catch all "violations". For example, the above will only work for `bin\debug`, but not for `bin\Debug` or other mixed-cased variations, which are functionally equivalent. To look for them as well, you'd need to call the `IndexOf(string, StringComparison)` overload, however just doing:

```
   $(HintPath.IndexOf('bin\debug', System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Will not work, because the MSBuild overload resolution will pick `IndexOf(char, Int32)` and give you this error:

> MSB4184: The expression ""bin\debug".IndexOf(bin\debug, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)" cannot be evaluated. String must be exactly one character long.

So, you'll need to convince it by using the `IndexOf(String, Int32, Int32, StringComparison)` overload directly:

```
   $(HintPath.IndexOf('bin\debug', 0, 9, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

You may need to also check for `bin\Release` or other variations. I'm not sure if that is the best way to figure out a reference should be a project reference, but if you know (and to a certain extend control) your environment it might be feasible.

Comment: This seems to work, though I need an additional condition for refs without HintPath. However, invoking msbuild for each reference is slow - my solution slowed from 2 sec to 34 secs! If there's no way to do it in the same msbuild instance, then it's not worth it for me.

Comment: @Jonathan I was toying around, trying to find a way to do it in the same MSBuild instance, but couldn't find any (short of writing your own task maybe).

Answer (score 0):

@Christian.K is right in his analysis. Another solution would be to force the overload of type string using `&quot;` for the quotes:

```
<Warning 
  Text="..." 
  Condition="$(HintPath.IndexOf(&quot;bin\debug&quot;, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1" />
```