# In MSBuild can you set per-file properties for all files once?

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to setup a simple rule for VS2010/MSBuild builds to reduce project management.  It's related to the 'ExcludedFromBuild' property.

The rule is, if the filename doesn't have the platform name in it, ExcludedFromBuild = true.

ie-

I have Win32Math.cpp & Win64Math.cpp.  I only want Win32Math to be compiled when I'm buliding the Win32 Platform.  Similar for Win64.

Setting this up per file is easy, but a bit tedious.  We have 4 platforms we're targeting, and each time we add a file we have to update properties for each target.  I want the rule to be global, so each time I add a platform file I don't have to go through the setup each time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you can't test intrinsic item metadata in `<ItemDefinitionGroup>`s. The only known way is to use a target.

```
<Target Name="RemoveNonPlatformItems" BeforeTargets="ClCompile">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ClCompile>
            <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="!$([System.String]::Copy(%(FileName)).Contains($(Platform)))">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
        </ClCompile>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Or even better:

```
<Target Name="RemoveNonPlatformItems" BeforeTargets="ClCompile">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ClCompile Remove="%(Identity)" Condition="!$([System.String]::Copy(%(FileName)).Contains($(Platform)))" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ítem definition groups for this kind of thing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629392.aspx, but I don't quite understand your specific situation. You'll probably need to set the metadata based on the item's filename matching the platform.

This shows how to use property functions with item metadata. [Using Item functions on metadata values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512577/using-item-functions-on-metadata-values)