# Conditional default item metadata

Tags: msbuild

I want all project files **under** `Content\**` to have `CopyToOutputDirectory` set to `PreserveNewest` by default while still having to add each item (**therefore no wildcard include**). Something like:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Content Include="Content\**\*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Unfortunately ItemDefinition does not support `Include` attribute.
I have also tried:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Content>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory Condition="$([System.String]::new('%(Identity)').StartsWith('Content\'))">PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9541282/443422) but it seems like it doesn't work in ItemDefinition.
In fact when I've attempted this:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Content>
    <CustomToolNamespace>Foo = $([System.String]::new(%(Identity)))</CustomToolNamespace>
  </Content>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

The value of CustomToolNamespace reported by Properties pane was `Foo = %(Identity)` .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new metadata for your Itemgroup:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Content>
       <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>

<Target Name="Definition">
   <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Content\**\*"/>
   </ItemGroup>

   <Message Text="%(Content.CopyToOutputDirectory)"/>
</Target>
</Project>
```

This adds the new metatdata to the itemgroup.

You could also combine two itemgroups based on different Includes and metadata like:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <WithContent>
       <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </WithContent>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>

<Target Name="Definition">
   <ItemGroup>
      <NotContent Include="Content\**\not*"/>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <WithContent Include="Content\**\with*"/>
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <Content Include="@(NotContent)"/>
     <Content  Include="@(WithContent)"/>
   </ItemGroup>

   <Message Text="Added together: %(Content.CopyToOutputDirectory)"/>
   <Message Text="Added together: %(Content.Identity)"/>

</Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: This will set `CopyToOutputDirectory` on all content, not just inside `Content\` and will include all files in that directory into project which is something I don't want to happen ("therefore no wildcard include").

Comment: yes It will do it fro any itemgroup called content. Theres noting stopping using another name or even multiple itemgroups and combining though.

Comment: I don't see how using another name would help. I need metadata on `<Content>`.

Comment: But I want to avoid wildcard include. I just need default value on items that are in project file.