# Set MSBuild properties on Build target input items based on metadata

Tags: msbuild

I'm using a code-generation tool (Entity Framework, in this case) in one of my projects, and it generates code that causes the compiler to emit warnings.  I'd like to ignore those warnings for a particular set of files.  My first thought was that I might be able to set up an `ItemGroup` to set per-file properties for the compiler, something semantically like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="Migrations/**/*.cs">
        <Properties>
            <DisabledWarnings>CS12345;CS4321</DisabledWarnings>
        </Properties>
    </Files>
</ItemGroup>
```

I recognize that this isn't valid MSBuild syntax, but it expresses the essence of what I'd like to do.

This question seems somewhat related: [Using Item functions on metadata values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512577/using-item-functions-on-metadata-values)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That is pretty much the msbuild syntax you'd use if it were for C++ (Files would be named ClCompile, and the option is DisableSpecificWarnings instead of DisabledWarnings). Unfrotunately for you I don't think it is possible to pass per-file compilation options to the Csc task for C#. To workaround that you could compile these files seperately in a custom pre-build step, or move them to a seperate project. Or hope someone else with more C# knowledge knows a way to pass per-file options.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use MSBuild to disable compiler warnings per file. Instead, you need to use `#pragma` statements in the code.

For example, lets say you wan to disable warnings about usage of obsolete APIs (build warning CS0618). You can surround the code like this to suppress the warning.

```
#pragma warning disable CS0618

public void Method()
{
   new Class1().CallSomeObsoleteMessage();
}

#pragma warning restore CS0618
```

Alternatively, you can disable warnings for an entire project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);CS0618</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```